# Excluir un valor de un array

Tags: php

Buenas tardes amigos tengo el siguiente array:

```
0 => array:7 [▼
0 => "12345678"
1 => "22222222"
2 => "12345678"
3 => "23232323"
4 => "12345678"
5 => "25252525"
6 => "12345678"
]
```

Estoy necesitando excluir el siguiente valor 12345678, pero al buscar en la documentación con la función unset  se puede eliminar un valor a la vez. El nombre de el array junto con el índice del elemento ($array[0]) se pasa como parámetro. El tema es que conozco el valor pero no el índice porque el array se forma dinámicamente según los valores obtenidos, lo único que conozco es el valor a eliminar, cómo puedo hacer esto? alguna ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Quizá pueda servirte `array_search()`. Intenta con esa función para obtener el índice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que esas usando PHP simplemente con un Foreach puedes hacer eso:

```
$array=[
0 => "12345678",
1 => "22222222",
2 => "12345678",
3 => "23232323",
4 => "12345678",
5 => "25252525",
6 => "12345678"];
```

Muestra solo los diferentes a 12345678

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($array) ; $i++) { 
        if ($array[$i]!="12345678"){ 
            echo $array[$i]."<br>";
        }
}
```

Te dejo un Ejemplo
https://3v4l.org/0QAII

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo tomado para hacerla, pero intenté meter el mismo código de varias formas en última me genera éste error Array to string conversion en el echo

Comment: Puedes subir tu código de Ejemplo acá https://3v4l.org/ para ayudarte más rápido

Comment: metí mi array y me generó exactamente el mismo resultado que tú estoy revisando mi código algo me debe estar faltando que genera error

Comment: Dale prueba y si no sube tu codigo a la web que te envie y asi vemos lo que tu vez, nos avisas

Comment: Encontré el error era mío acepté tu respuesta ya que me fue genial, gracias